# Pattern unlock is too small after 4.4.2 update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens

I go to unlock my phone with the pattern but it is now smaller and I keep going into camera instead.  Is there ANY way to turn this off?  If the phone is locked I want emergency calls or unlock - never camera.  It is driving me doo-daly.

Comment: Please mention your phone model too.

Comment: In addition to what @JaskaranbirSingh said, could you post a picture to let us know how smaller is this pattern that you mentioned?